# Knowing that liminf $x_n$ and limsup $x_n$ are in [-1,1], how to express this using big-O, small-o notation?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, limsup-and-liminf

I have a sequence $(x_n)$ with a property that $\liminf x_n \in [-1,1]$ and $\limsup x_n \in [-1,1]$.
I'd like to express this property using big-O and small-o somehow.

I'm thinking:

1. $x_n = \gamma + o(1)$ where $\gamma \in [-1,1]$

   (I don't think this is right since we don't know if $x_n$ converges to $\gamma$ or not, we only know that $x_n$ fall in $[-1,1]$ for large $n$)

or I can express this as:

2. $x_n \ge -1 - |o(1)| $ and  $x_n \le 1 + |o(1)| $

   (I use absolute value to get positive sequence $o(1)$).
   I've always seen "$= o(1)$" with equality, and never seen inequalities "$ > o(1)$" or "$ < o(1)$", so I'm not sure if this is right.

Do you think (2) is correct or how would to write it?

Thank you!

Comment: $$|x_n|\leqslant1+o(1)$$

Comment: @Did I'm courios.. How do you define $a_n\le o(1)$?

Comment: @Exodd As usual, $a_k\leqslant o(1)$ means that $a_k\leqslant b_k$ for every $k$, for some sequence $(b_k)$ such that $b_k=o(1)$ (what else?). Thus, $a_k\leqslant o(1)$ is equivalent to $\limsup a_k\leqslant0$. Why do you ask?

Comment: Equivalent, but not using $o$ or $O$: $$\limsup|x_n|\leqslant1$$

Answer (score 2):

All you can say in those notations (and if you want $x_n$ alone on the left of the equality sign) is that 
$$ x_n=O(1)$$
(or equivalently $x_n=c+O(1)$ for arbitrary $c$). We do *not* have $x_n=o(1)$ because the sequence $x_n=(-1)^n$ would be a valid example with $\frac{x_n}{1}\not \to 0$.

At any rate, the notations "$<o(1)$" or similar are not defined (though one could think of a way to come up with a suitable definition). Recall that even the $=$ in $f(n)=O(g(n)$ is an abuse of notation. A more formal approach would be to consider $O(g(n))$ a *set* of functions and write $f\in O(g)$.

Also note that adding an absolute value is meaningless (in the problem at hand). Again, recall that the definition of the Landau symbols involves taking absolute values anyway.

Comment: "All you can say in those notations is..." I wish to disagree, see my comment.

Comment: @Did: Without making use of an inequality in the way you did for your comment, I think Hagen von Eitzen has the best one could hope to say with an equality (which was how I misread your comment when I tagged you in a response to it).

Comment: O(1) just means it is a bounded sequence. I want it to be more specific than that. It is a sequence that eventually fall in interval [-1,1], not just any bounded one.

Comment: @user262959 The O notation is specifically for cases where you don't care about certain constants. So if you *do* care, just say it the way you want/need it. - By the way, the given conditions on $\liminf $ and $\limsup$ do *not* entail that the sequence eventually falls in $[-1,1]$. Consider $x_n=(1+\frac1n)\sin n$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The OP kind of said that they cared about the $[-1,1]$ setting.